# Long HTTP GET request in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, http, get, windows-runtime

I have the following code for Windows Phone 8.1. It's compiled and run as Universal application.

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(myphoneChannelUrl);
            //var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://ya.ru");

            // Place 1
            stream.ReadByte();
            // Place 2
        }
```

I want to use a very long "GET" request to organize notification channel for my app.
Server sends me a string "START". In Wireshark I see that server responds immediately. After 10 seconds it sends me string "NEXT".

The problem is that somehow it takes exactly 10 seconds to read one byte from the stream. Actually only after receiving "NEXT" I can read "START" and "NEXT" immediately.

After that next read from stream will block forever while I see there's some data coming from the server.

If I use "GET" on some ordinary page like google.com which sends me data and closes connection I get response immediately.

UPD: Please, note that server sends data in chunked transfer encoding. I suppose there are no troubles with server since all other clients ( especially .NET 4.0 for example ) work fine with this stream.

Comment: Are you using `ReadAsInputStream` and `DataReader`? If yes, how are you calling these methods. If you noticed a pattern, why don't you send the first "hello" message in two TCP packages?

Comment: I put here the simplest code which doesn't work. If you can suggest working solution it would be nice but I tried different variants for a long time. In the end I solved this issue using plain StreamSocket. Now I can control timeouts, cancellations, amount of data read e.t.c. by myself.